# Mercurial log questions

Tags: logging, mercurial

How do you find the actual date of an hg transplant?   On Sept 7, several files were transplanted with the command:

```
hg transplant -b <branch> --log abcdefg
```

On Sept 10, the command `hg log --date "2012-09-07 to 2012-09-10"` was running.  However, this does not display the changeset of the transplanted files because the date has the parent commit date which was in August.

How can I do an hg log (or something) on a branch with a date range that will show me transplants?

Answer (score 2):

At this point you're out of luck.  This is one of the reasons that `transplant` isn't a standard part of any *good* workflow.  It (and `git cherry-pick`) are fine for when someone did some work in the *wrong* branch, but they shouldn't be necessary in normal usage.  The `merge` command is the preferred way to get changes from one branch to another -- and if you're always fixing bugs at the earliest point in history where they could be fixed `hg merge` should be a safe way to bring them into any branch where they exist without bringing any other changes.  The 2010 Joel of Software/Kiln roadshow video includes a great explanation of why picking the right parent for a fix makes `merge` always the better choice.

Not quite as good as `merge` but still better than `transplant` is the `graft` command which takes a `--currentdate` argument if you want to override the date of the changeset you're moving.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think you can.**  Once a changeset is committed, you can't go back and change anything about it.  It looks like `transplant` keeps/uses the original changesets timestamp.

You can use the `extras` template field to show/find all the transplants in your repository.  I believe for a transplanted changeset, there will be a `source` key/value pair in `extras` with the changeset ID of the original changeset.

```
$ hg log --template '{extras}'
```

You can then pass that output to grep to get just the transplants.